# Why are files with CRLF not available to add to the index when normalizing?

Tags: git

So I've been following the instructions of the various pages covering end of line normalization.

.gitattributes contains the following and has been committed.

```
* text=auto

core.autocrlf = input

core.eol unset (defaults to native)
```

My objective is to normalize all text files in the repository so that they contain LF's only and future checkins do the same.

What I find is that files exist in my working area (this is after deleting the working files and performing a `git reset --hard`) contain CRLF however they are not listed when I perform a "git status".

I can checkout another branch then return to the branch and sometimes (this is very inconsistent) the file is then listed as something that ought to be committed.

It gets more interesting...

After I commit all files that git notes as converting CRLF's to LF's, checkout another branch, then checkout the first branch again and a whole new set of files are listed via `get status` indicating that they too have CRLF's that will be normalized to LF's. Why weren't these caught the first time?

It seems like files, on checkout, leak through with a CR and are not flagged as needing to be committed (sometimes).

Am I missing something? (or, rather, what am I missing?)

Using git 1.8.3.2 on Mac OS X

Comment: First of all, this is all you need in your `.gitattributes` file, you don't need any of that other stuff: `* text=auto`. Second, have you tried the instructions in [Re-normalizing a repository from the GitHub help page on dealing with line-endings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings#re-normalizing-a-repository)?

Comment: The formatting is off in my original post - the only thing in .gitattributes is "* text=auto". The core.autocrlf and core.eol are my configuration settings. Yea, I've been following the instructions to which you refer. Essentially, I would expect to run it once and all affected files would be included in the first round. What I'm seeing is that I can return to the same code, run it again, and get a) another set of files to commit or b) I find files with carriage returns *still* that are not flagged as needing commit.

Comment: So here's a data point. After creating the .gitattributes file, removing all of the other files, and running "git reset --hard" there are 43 files changes detected by "git status". If I run "grep -I -c -r $'\r' * | wc -l" I get 8589 text files (mostly .java) that contain carriage returns. Shouldn't all of those 8589 files have shown up as changes by "git status"?